# ViewPager not showing correct View

Tags: android

I'm using the V4 compatibility JAR.  I have a ViewPager that shows information about some bands.  When I create the PagerAdapter, I pass it an ArrayList of Band objects.

In the emulator, it always shows shows the 2nd band in the ArrayList's information first.  When I flip to the last view, the view always has no data.  When I flip back and forth, the data then gets really buggy.

**BandsActivity**

```
private ViewPager mBandsPager;
private BandsPagerAdapter mBandsPagerAdapter;
private static final String TAG = "Paging";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.awesomepager);

    // Build a couple bands;
    ArrayList<Band> bands = new ArrayList<Band>();
    bands.add(new Band(1, "Led Zeppelin"));
    bands.add(new Band(37, "Brand New"));
    bands.add(new Band(49, "Jay-Z"));

    mBandsPagerAdapter = new BandsPagerAdapter(this, bands);

    mBandsPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.awesomepager);
    mBandsPager.setAdapter(mBandsPagerAdapter);

}
```

**BandsPagerAdapter**

```
private Context mCtx;
private ArrayList<Band> mBands;

public BandsPagerAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<Band> bands) {
    mCtx = ctx;
    mBands = bands;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mBands.size();
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

    // Inflate and create the view
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)mCtx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.featured_bands_layout, null);

    // Build UI
    TextView name = (TextView)collection.findViewById(R.id.featured_band_name);

    // Populate UI with band data
    Band band = mBands.get(position);
    if(name != null) {
        name.setText("Name: " + band.getName() + ", Pos: " + position);
    }

    // Add View to the ViewPager collection
    ((ViewPager)collection).addView(view,0);

    return view;
}


@Override
public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view) {

    ((ViewGroup) collection).removeView((View)view);
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view==((View)object);
}


@Override
public void finishUpdate(View arg0) {}


@Override
public void restoreState(Parcelable arg0, ClassLoader arg1) {}

@Override
public Parcelable saveState() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void startUpdate(View arg0) {}
```

Any suggestions?  I saw a mention of implementing ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener, but didn't see how it could be used properly.

Comment: it's nothing related to answer, but change "collection.findViewById" to "view.findViewById", it's more appropriate.

Comment: You activity will b re-created when you rotate your screen, thus the context will be changed; so in way, your pageadaptor is holding on to a context that should no longer exist, and will result in a memory leak!

Comment: That turns out to be the right answer!  I needed to use the view object I just inflated.

TextView name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.featured_band_name);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your BandsPagerAdapter seems to be the problem. Here's how I would implement it. See if it makes a difference!

```
public class BandsPagerAdapter extends PageAdaptor{

    private ArrayList<Band> mBands;

    public BandsPagerAdapter(ArrayList<Band> bands) {
        mBands = bands;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mBands.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

        // Inflate and create the view
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.featured_bands_layout, null);

        // Build UI
        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.featured_band_name);

        // Populate UI with band data
        Band band = mBands.get(position);
        if(name != null) {
            name.setText("Name: " + band.getName() + ", Pos: " + position);
        }

        // Add View to the ViewPager collection
        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view,0);

        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view) 
        ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((View) view);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((View) object);
    }


    @Override
    public void finishUpdate(View arg0) {}


    @Override
    public void restoreState(Parcelable arg0, ClassLoader arg1) {}

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void startUpdate(View arg0) {}
}
```

Comment: Perfect!  Like I said above, you must use the inflated view.  Bonus points for using the Context from the collection to avoid memory leaks.